# What is the endpoint of the EC2 linux1 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 linux1 instance and I SSH into it. I installed NodeJS and cloned a git repository to the instance. The app is successfully running and connected to the MySQL database instance I created from the RDS. Assume the app name is `my-app`. What I want is to be able to access the the app on the server.

**I tried**

```
- ec2-{Public DNS (IPv4)}.compute-1.amazonaws.com/my-app/{endpoint} (not working)

- {Public DNS (IPv4)}/my-app/{endpoint} (not working) (not working)
```

The security group of the instance is set like below:

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you access the app locally using `curl`? What port is it running on?

Comment: @DanielScott yes, I can access it locally and it return data when I set the endpoint like this 'localhost:400/my-app/{end_point}. it is a NodeJS backend for `APIs`

Comment: Then you need to either open port 400 on your security group, or use a firewall to forward port 80 or 443 to 400.

Comment: @DanielScott Thank u it works, I added custom TCP with port 4000

Comment: Note that port numbers 0 to 1023 are typically reserved for privileged services and designated as well-known ports. If you are serving HTTP/HTTPS then you can use 80/443, otherwise you would typically use a port number above 1023.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is running on port 4000, you need to either open that port in your security group, or add a firewall/reverse proxy to forward from 80/443 to 4000.

You can use iptables to forward the port:

[Forwarding traffic from 80 to 8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828853/forwarding-traffic-from-80-to-8080)

or apache as a reverse proxy:

[Apache redirect to another port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541182/apache-redirect-to-another-port)

Comment: can you please explain how to to add a firewall/reverse proxy to forward from 80.443 to 4000?

Comment: Edited answer to include links. There are almost unlimited ways of doing this.

Comment: when i try to access it through `https` i got error. but i believe that i defined the HTTPS in the security group as in the attached image in the question, do you know why this is happening?

Comment: What error do you get? If https is setup properly for the app, then you can just use `https://example.com:4000/my-app/{end_point}`.

Comment: When i use `http://example.com:4000/my-app/{end_point}` it prints data on the broweser, but when i replace `http` with `https` i got `This site can’t provide a secure connection` and got invalid response

Comment: Then you need to setup your app webserver with tls.

Comment: I actually added the `HTTPS` rule to the security group for the web server. I will create another question for this issue as it is different, I hope you can help out with this issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430754/ec2-instance-server-not-accepting-https-requests