# EC2 instance server not accepting HTTPS requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I Created an EC2 instance that is running perfectly over http.but when i try to replace `http` to `https` i got this printed on the browser `This site can’t provide a secure connection`. the security group that is associated to this instance is configured to allow requests from both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` as in the attached image:

[image]

Comment: Have you configured SSL on the web-server? For that matter, what web-server are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to run https over a port that has been configured for HTTP.

There are multiple options to get around this:

- Setup a [proxy on your local server](https://medium.com/@nimit95/a-simple-http-https-proxy-in-node-js-4eb0444f38fc), such as Nginx. Setup [certbot](https://medium.com/@nimit95/a-simple-http-https-proxy-in-node-js-4eb0444f38fc) to generate your SSL and then serve this from your proxy.
- Create an [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) in front of your server, generate a certificate in ACM and add your server as a target (running http) to the ELB. Use the load balancer for SSL termination.
- Create a [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) distribution in front of your server, generate a certificate in ACM and forward traffic to your server as the origin (running http).

Comment: You can also use Lets Encrypt and use the certificates generated by that and add the location of the certificates in the Virtual Host of your site. It should start working over https. This is a low cost solution.

Comment: Correct @MuzaffarShaikh this is now known as certbot :)